# How to get MPMediaItemCollection knowing its item url?

Tags: swift, avplayer, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

I save item URL:

```
var itemUrl: URL? = nil
itemUrl = (qryAlbums.collections[currAlbum].items[currItem].assetURL!)

let tempString: String = (track.last?.value(forKey: “url”) as! String?)!

track.setValue(itemUrl?.absoluteString, forKey: “url”)
```

now i can play this item with AVPLayer:

```
AudioPlayerManager.sharedInstance.play(itemUrl)
```

Q: Now having items url how i can get collection and item index ?

Comment: How do you know a given url only exists in one collection?

Comment: I explain what i need.
This is a music player. App saves last played track. On the next launch that track is on start screen. Collection needed for the rewind and forward from the saved track.